# WCF ASync Method Not Called

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF service which is workng fine but I now want to make the calls to its method asynchronous. In VS2010, I have re-added the service reference in the client and selected the checkbox for async methods. However, now when I call MyMethodAsync() instead of MyMethod() nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe for the success callback. Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx) that shows an example:

```
client.MyMethodCompleted += new EventHandler<MyMethodCompletedEventArgs>(MyMethodCallback);
client.MyMethodAsync(parameters);
```

`MyMethodAsync` returns immediately and the `MyMethodCallback` function will be invoked once the operation completes and it will be passed as argument the result of the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Where does MyMethodCompletedEventArgs come from? What parameter types does MyMethodCallback take? Just IAsyncResult?

Comment: @Jonnster, the `MyMethodCompletedEventArgs` should be defined in the generated proxy. The actual class might be called differently based on the method name that you are trying to invoke. As far as the `MyMethodCallback` is concerned it takes two parameters: the sender (of type `object`) and the event argument which is of type `MyMethodCompletedEventArgs`.

Comment: No the ...CompletedEventArgs were not created. This is why I asked. I assumed that they would be. It created all the other bits but not the EventArgs one. I tried deleting and starting again but still not.

Comment: @Jonnster, does the method you are trying to invoke take arguments? Simply look at the definition of the `MyMethodCompleted` event and you should know how to wire it up.